# *.cfg: permission denied while building workspace

Tags: ros, catkin-ws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am making a custom robot for my final year project, for the robot to work, I was given a custom catkin_ws file.
I followed the steps mention here

http://answers.ros.org/question/193901/how-to-migrate-a-catkin-workspace/

and after following the steps, this occurred.

```
ros@ros-desktop:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/ros/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/ros/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/ros/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/ros/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/ros/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/ros/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _rosserial_arduino_generate_messages_check_deps_Test
Built target _rosserial_arduino_generate_messages_check_deps_Adc
[  0%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Log
[  0%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RequestParam
[  6%] Built target serial
[ 11%] Built target merlin_hostbot
[ 11%] [ 11%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RequestMessageInfo
Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_TopicInfo
[ 11%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RequestServiceInfo
[ 13%] Built target quaternion2yaw_node
[ 16%] [ 20%] Built target stm_hostbot
Generating dynamic reconfigure files from cfg/CalibrateAngular.cfg: /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel/include/rbx1_nav/CalibrateAngularConfig.h /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rbx1_nav/cfg/CalibrateAngularConfig.py
/home/ros/catkin_ws/build/rbx1/rbx1_nav/setup_custom_pythonpath.sh: 4: exec: /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/rbx1/rbx1_nav/cfg/CalibrateAngular.cfg: Permission denied
make[2]: * [/home/ros/catkin_ws/devel/include/rbx1_nav/CalibrateAngularConfig.h] Error 126
make[1]: * [rbx1/rbx1_nav/CMakeFiles/rbx1_nav_gencfg.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: * Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 23%] [ 25%] Built target urg_c_wrapper
Generating dynamic reconfigure files from cfg/URG.cfg: /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel/include/urg_node/URGConfig.h /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urg_node/cfg/URGConfig.py
/home/ros/catkin_ws/build/urg_node/setup_custom_pythonpath.sh: 4: exec: /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/urg_node/cfg/URG.cfg: Permission denied
make[2]: * [/home/ros/catkin_ws/devel/include/urg_node/URGConfig.h] Error 126
make[1]: * [urg_node/CMakeFiles/urg_node_gencfg.dir/all] Error 2
[ 27%] Built target user_publisher
make: * [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252836/*.cfg:-permission-denied-while-building-workspace/) by [Acecryz](https://answers.ros.org/users/28951/acecryz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-01-23

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-24**:
I am only a beginner but the -j4 usually means use 4 cores  on the processor.  Could you try changing -j4 to -j1

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-24**:
I've updated the title of your question to better reflect what is the problem (and to also differentiate it a bit from the million other "make -j4 -l4 failed" questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> /home/ros/catkin_ws/build/rbx1/rbx1_nav/setup_custom_pythonpath.sh: 4: exec: /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/rbx1/rbx1_nav/cfg/CalibrateAngular.cfg: Permission denied
> ```

```
...
/home/ros/catkin_ws/build/urg_node/setup_custom_pythonpath.sh: 4: exec: /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/urg_node/cfg/URG.cfg: Permission denied
```

have you extracted these files from a zip file, or copied them from a usb stick or Windows share?

Those `.cfg` files (they are files for [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure)) should have their executable bit set, and they currently probably don't have it, that's why you get the *Permission denied* errors.

Try and see what the output is of:

```
ls -al /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/rbx1/rbx1_nav/cfg/CalibrateAngular.cfg
```

and:

```
ls -al /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/urg_node/cfg/URG.cfg
```

If it doesn't include the `x` bit for both you and other users, then do a:

```
chmod +x /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/rbx1/rbx1_nav/cfg/CalibrateAngular.cfg
```

and:

```
chmod +x /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/urg_node/cfg/URG.cfg
```

and try again.

---

PS:

> [..] I was given a custom catkin_ws file.

Pedantic perhaps, but note that 'catkin_ws' is typically a *directory*, not a single file.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7